# I just want to append text to an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, map-function

Now for every item that has the string "shirt", I want to replace shirt to "Shirts are not available

```
const inventory = [
        { line_item_id: "55412", item: "Shirt small", description: "" },
        { line_item_id: "55342", item: "shirt big full", description: "" },
        { line_item_id: "1124",  item: "Pant Small",description: "",},
    ];
```

I want it to look like this

```
const inventory = [
    { line_item_id: "55412", item: "Shirts are not available small", description: "" },
    { line_item_id: "55342", item: "Shirts are not available big full", description: "" },
    { line_item_id: "1124",  item: "Pant Small",description: "",},
];
```

I have used the map function, but it does not including rows that weren’t modified

**My code**

```
  const test = convertedToJson.map((convertedToJson) => {
        if (!!convertedToJson.item.match(/Shirt/i)) {
            return convertedToJson.item + "Shirts are not available  ";
        }
    });
    console.log(test);
```

"My output"

```
const inventory = [
       'Shirts are not available small'
        'Shirts are not available big full'
    ];
```

Comment: That is not the output you get when you run your code. There is no `.match(/Shirts/i)` with plural `Shirts` in `item`, So, it returns an array of `undefined`s. Also, use `forEach` instead of `map` if you want to replace a property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const convertedInventory = inventory.map((it) => {
  const reg = new RegExp(/Shirt/i);
  if (it.item.match(reg)) {
    return {
      ...it,
      item: it.item.replace(reg, 'Shirts are not available')
    }
  }
  return it;
})
```

Comment: Please add  some context when you answer, it is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map & replace

```js
const inventory = [{
    line_item_id: "55412",
    item: "Shirt small",
    description: ""
  },
  {
    line_item_id: "55342",
    item: "shirt big full",
    description: ""
  },
  {
    line_item_id: "1124",
    item: "Pant Small",
    description: "",
  },
];

const newVal = inventory.map((elem) => {
  // checking if string contains shirt/Shirt
  if (elem.item.toLowerCase().indexOf('shirt') !== -1) {
    return {
      ...elem,
      // case-insensitive replacement
      item: elem.item.replace(/shirt/gi, "Shirts are not available")

    }
  } else {
    return { ...elem
    }
  }
});

console.log(newVal)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const test = convertedToJson.map((convertedToJson) => {
        if (convertedToJson.item.toLowerCase().indexOf('shirt') !== -1) {
            convertedToJson.item = convertedToJson.item.replace(/shirt/gi, "Shirts are not available");
        }
        return convertedToJson
    });
    console.log(test);
```

The problem with your code is you are returning value only if if condition got satisfied. I just return the value outside, and if 'if condition' got satisfied the value will be manipulated

Answer (score 0):

This way...

```js
const inventory = 
  [ { line_item_id: "55412", item: "Shirt small",    description: "" } 
  , { line_item_id: "55342", item: "shirt big full", description: "" } 
  , { line_item_id: "1124",  item: "Pant Small",     description: "" } 
  ] 

inventory.forEach((obj,i,arr)=>
  arr[i].item = obj.item.replace(/shirt/i, 'Shirts are not available'))

console.log( inventory )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using `Array.prototype.map`.

```js
const inventory = [{
    line_item_id: "55412",
    item: "Shirt small",
    description: ""
  },
  {
    line_item_id: "55342",
    item: "shirt big full",
    description: ""
  },
  {
    line_item_id: "1124",
    item: "Pant Small",
    description: ""
  },
];

const result = inventory.map((el) => {
  if (el.item.toLowerCase().includes("shirt")) {
    return { ...el,
      item: "Shirts are not available small"
    };
  }
  return el;
});


console.log( result );
```